# In "Сокровища кровавого Рокама": what is the case and number of "сокровища"?

Tags: грамматика

Tintin's adventure "Le Trésor de Rackham le Rouge" has been translated into Russian as "Сокровища кровавого Рокама".
I don't understand the syntax of "Сокровища" here: "treasure" is translated in dictionaries as "cокровищe" and "cокровища" seems to be the genitive.
Is it a plural? But then should it not be be "cокровищя", since it is the plural of a neutral noun of the soft type?
What's going on? Might it be a dirty trick of Rastapopoulos, Tintin's archenemy?

Comment: Ah, I got a downvote within less than one minute. Rastapopoulos must be very angry!

Comment: I've down-voted you question because it's not clear why exactly you've assumed that the plural is "сокровищя". First it's easily googled, second, "щя" just not happens in Russian at all.

Comment: @shabunc: your appreciation on the ease of googling is of no help whatever and there is no reason I should explain to you why I think  that the plural is "сокровищя". By the way it's "your question", not "you question".  And "just not happens" is an incorrect substitute for "just doesn't happen".

Comment: Oh, I’m doing a lot of mistakes while I’m on the phone, thank you for correcting me! As of “there’s no reason I should explain you why” - whatever, you’ve just been wondering why it was down-voted - and I explained myself.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @shabunc. But I liked my conjecture that Rastapopoulos was the culprit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An addition to [Alissa](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/1836/alissa)'s answer.
In Russian, the letters **Я** and **Ю** are forbidden after the letters **Ч** and **Щ** which stand for soft (palatal) consonants [tʃ] and [ʃː]. Instead, **А** and **У** are written after **Ч** and **Щ**, never **Я** and **Ю**. Also, the letter **Ы** is never written after **Ж** and **Ш**, although these two letters stand for hard (non-palatal) consonants [ʐ] and [ʂ], **И** is written instead. These rules about the vowel letters after **Ж** and **Ш**, **Ч** and **Щ** are usually grouped and studied together:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your wonderfully clear explanations, dear Yellow Sky. And I'm quite ashamed of my ignorance, since I had already"studied" (ahem)  these incompatibility rules.

Answer (score 6):

Сокровища is a plural here. In Russian "сокровище" means a precious item (just one). So if there is a chest (or a pile) of precious items, it would be plural — "сокровища".

Comment: Thank you very much, Alissa: this is quite interesting, since in French "trésor"  does have a plural, but it wouldn't sound so natural in this context. Is there a "reason" ( I know, this is a dangerous term in linguistics!) why the plural is сокровища rather than cокровищя? (and +1, of course.)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't accept your answer as well as Yellow Sky's, dear Alissa. Both answers are very instructive and my choice is a bit arbitrary.

Comment: That's OK. It appears that I missed the part about spelling of the plural form. As for a "reason" behind the rule, I guess that "Ч" and "Щ" are already soft, so we needn't use iotized vowels for further softening. But that's probably just my rationalization.

Comment: Thanks again, dear Alissa. Yours seems to be a quite plausible explanation.

Comment: I think `treasure`/`treasures` are better suited English equivalents to both `сокровище` and `trésor`(I bet they're even related).